# QGraphicsScene addRect incorrect render

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I use QGraphicsView widget with attached QGraphicsScene in my program.
This part works perfect:

```
    std::vector<unsigned int> nodesCoordsOnScreen;
    for(int i=0; i<nodesCoords.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int tempCoord = spaceH+nodesCoords.at(i)*perOneMmH;
        graphVW->scene()->addEllipse(tempCoord, -4, 8, 8, standartPen);
        QGraphicsTextItem* tempText = graphVW->scene()->addText(QString::number(i+1));
        tempText->setPos(tempCoord+8, 0);
        graphVW->scene()->addEllipse(tempCoord+8, 5, 15, 15, standartPen);
        nodesCoordsOnScreen.push_back(tempCoord);
    }
```

and this has troubles:

```
    for(int i=0; i<bars->rowCount(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int begin = barsCoords.at(i).first;
        unsigned int end = barsCoords.at(i).second;
        unsigned int begCrd = nodesCoordsOnScreen.at(begin-1);
        unsigned int endCrd = nodesCoordsOnScreen.at(end-1);
        graphVW->scene()->addRect(begCrd+4, (barsAreas.at(i)/2)*perOneMmV, endCrd-begCrd,
                              -(barsAreas.at(i))*perOneMmV, standartPen);
    }
```

The trouble is strange: when the second part renders - it renders incorrect, but if I move program window or minimize it and return to normal state - it renders correct.

Comment: We need [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you.

Comment: I can give the link to github with all this program, but some text there is not on english

Comment: I just can't do screenshot because render become normal when I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to use QtGraphicsScene::update() after drawings.